# ¿Si tengo una tabla desordenada y quiero hacer una consulta de selección como la ordenaría previamente?

Tags: sql-server

Suponiendo que mi tabla no tiene definido un índice y quiero ordenar la columna `id` de las tablas `T1` y `T2` antes de aplicar la consulta de selección combinada de abajo:

¿Cómo ordeno `id` de `T1` y `T2` previamente, antes de aplicar la consulta de abajo?

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id_t2 = T2.id
```

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta apunta a que al no tener índice,  ordenar ambas tablas previamente mejoraría la performance?

Comment: ¿A qué obedece que quieras _ordenar_ una tabla antes del `select`? Pregunto porque es algo que no está bajo tu control, en una consulta tu puedes ordenar el resultado. Del resto, se encarga el motor. Si has declarado llaves primarias y foráneas, los índices existirán para hacer óptima la consulta, pues el motor los crea al declarar las llaves.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que dices no tiene ningún sentido. Las tablas no tienen un orden definido ni siquiera con un índice(eso está definidio por la teoría relacional y es bueno que lo comprendas).

Por otro lado, todos los lenguajes basados en el estándar SQL son básicamente declarativos. Esto significa que le debes decir al manejador que es lo que quieres que se haga y dejar que el manejador decida cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo dependiendo de los índices disponibles, la cantidad de información y la distribución de la misma. SQL Server tiene 3 operaciones internas para unir dos tablas mediante JOINs ([merge, hash match y nested loops](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/showplan-logical-and-physical-operators-reference?view=sql-server-2017)) y no todas necesitan que exista un orden dentro de las tablas.

Finalmente, lo que seguramente quieres es que tu resultado tenga un orden definido. Eso se logra mediante la cláusula `ORDER BY` y sólo ordena el resultado final, no las tablas. Es de las últimas operaciones que realizará el manejador antes de regresar el resultado que hayas pedido.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Cual es el misterio, si puedes Ordenar las consulta como tu quieras.

```
Select * from mitabla order by campo1, campo2 desc
```

Los registros vienen ya ordenados 'campo1' de forma ascendente y 'campo2'  en orden descendente gracias a la clausula 'desc'.

ahora, juega con las distintas posibilidades, el limite lo pone tu imaginación.

Saludos.

Comment: Ah, si te entendí bien, primero ordeno con la consulta como tu ejemplo y luego ejecuto mi consulta como la que puse?

Comment: Pero pensándolo bien yo no quiero mostrar datos, sólo quiero ordenar la columna para luego aplicar una consulta de unión (LEFT JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres que el resultado final este ordenado no?

Para eso no hace falta ordenar previamente los datos de las tablas; al join no le interesa realmente si las tablas están ordenadas y/o tienen índices (bueno... por tema de performance sí, pero es otra historia).

Puedes utilizar el join como lo tienes y agregar la cláusula de ordenamiento al final de la misma

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id_t2 = T2.id
ORDER BY T1.id_t2
```

En este caso se debe ordenar por T1.id_t2 porque al ser un left join pueden haber resultados de T2 sin datos (NULL).

Comment: Ah, ok, entiendo, gracias por la respuesta.